Boy watching TV and an elephant or a rabbit teddy appears on the TV and says something
I've been trying to identify this movie for years. I remember watching a bit of it as a kid. I'm not sure if the genre is horror or not.
The clip I remember is of a child, a boy I think, looking at the TV. Then an elephant or a rabbit teddy of some kind appears on the TV and says something along the lines of "If you don't find me, you will die". Then the kid screams.
I can't remember much as I saw this years ago as a kid, maybe about 15-20 years ago.

This is a very rough guess, but there is a scene quite similiar to the one you describe in the Malcom in the middle Episode Cheerleader S01e12 (first telecasted in 2000)
Dewey wants to have a blue elephant teddy called herbie, when watching the commercial he dreams the teddy says:

All of the boys and girls on your street are my friends.
  They all bought me.
  Your parents have lots of money.
  They're just hiding it.
  But I don't want you to buy me for me.
  It's for your own good.
  I didn't want to tell you this, but if you don't buy me, you'll die.

You can see the scene here:



